# Объявление методов

Tags: javascript

Объясните этот пример:

```
var test = {
    test1(){
        alert('test');
    }
}
test.test1();
```

Т. е. тут не используется `function`.
Не нашёл описания данного синтаксиса в интернете.
В каких случаях можно не использовать `function` при назначении метода?
Это обычный геттер?

Answer (score 4):

Это объявление метода объекта.
Методы имеют некоторые отличия от функций и ключей.
[Подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

В любых случаях можно не использовать, если это объявление метода:

```
var obj = {
  property( parameters… ) {},
  *generator( parameters… ) {},
  async property( parameters… ) {},
  async* generator( parameters… ) {},

  // with computed keys:
  [property]( parameters… ) {},
  *[generator]( parameters… ) {},
  async [property]( parameters… ) {},

  // compare getter/setter syntax:
  get property() {},
  set property(value) {}
};
```

Геттер может быть создан, если поставить перед определением метода `get`:

```js
let obj = {
  z () {
    console.info('I am obj.z method');
  },
  
  get n () {
    return 42;
  }
};

console.info(obj.n);
```

Заметка: методы нельзя использовать как конструкторы:

```js
let obj = {
  f: function () {},
  m () {}
};

console.info(new obj.f()); // {}
console.info(new obj.m()); // TypeError: ...
```

Comment: Может чуть чуть подробней опишите? А то похоже на ответ-ссылку

Comment: что-то рекомендация вносить полезную инфу в ответ, а не просто оставлять ссылку, становится более актуальной, а то _"Ошибка при установлении защищённого соединения"_ © РКН (не для самой статьи, а для фрейма https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net, но тем не менее, и developer.mozilla.org довольно часто не работает)

Comment: гораздо лучше, спасибо :) Вопрос небольшой - это всегда так было или новый синтаксис? Я не в теме, но вроде лет 5-6 назад надо было использовать ключевое слово `function`?

Comment: Да, новинка. Хотя как новинка, конечно, в нашем скоротечном мире...